# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str (Display prediction text with putText from a list)

Tags: python, typeerror, deepface

I am having trouble displaying the "dominant_emotion" text from the 'prediction' on an image using deepface and cv2

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from deepface import DeepFace

img = cv2.imread('img.jpeg')

#analyze data from image

predictions = DeepFace.analyze(img)
```

```
{'emotion': {'angry': 6.107392927014836e-16,
  'disgust': 5.690325247443356e-32,
  'fear': 2.5075101390144196e-17,
  'happy': 99.99998807907104,
  'sad': 2.0470146844947523e-10,
  'surprise': 9.660542366063396e-08,
  'neutral': 1.3001614718177734e-05},
 'dominant_emotion': 'happy',
 'region': {'x': 94, 'y': 33, 'w': 128, 'h': 128},
 'age': 22,
 'gender': {'Woman': 0.4476664587855339, 'Man': 99.55233335494995},
 'dominant_gender': 'Man',
 'race': {'asian': 95.63242845148702,
  'indian': 0.41690156481843416,
  'black': 0.00915119198956287,
  'white': 0.572947251296371,
  'middle eastern': 0.007479770119618089,
  'latino hispanic': 3.3610902445208737},
 'dominant_race': 'asian'}
```

```
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.1,4)

# draw rectangle around face
for (x, y ,w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
 
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

cv2.putText(img, predictions['dominant_emotion'], (0,50), font, 3, (0,0,255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)
```

Resulting in the following error

```
>TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[55], line 3
      1 font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
 3 cv2.putText(img, predictions['dominant_emotion'], (0,50), font, 3, (0,0,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I have tried calling it in various ways and don't know how to convert the 'predictions' into a dictionary instead of a list

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code with a sample image. Here's your solution:

```
import cv2
from deepface import DeepFace

img = cv2.imread('/content/download.jpeg')

#analyze data from image

predictions = DeepFace.analyze(img)
print(predictions)
```

Output:

```
[{'emotion': {'angry': 1.373809203505516,
   'disgust': 1.433073038015209e-05,
   'fear': 0.5467387847602367,
   'happy': 1.279526948928833,
   'sad': 1.6416685655713081,
   'surprise': 0.004783821714227088,
   'neutral': 95.15345692634583},
  'dominant_emotion': 'neutral',
  'region': {'x': 67, 'y': 36, 'w': 113, 'h': 113},
  'age': 32,
  'gender': {'Woman': 0.0028732340069836937, 'Man': 99.99712705612183},
  'dominant_gender': 'Man',
  'race': {'asian': 1.3423374854028225,
   'indian': 1.2193581089377403,
   'black': 0.13639548560604453,
   'white': 53.03038954734802,
   'middle eastern': 19.4591224193573,
   'latino hispanic': 24.812400341033936},
  'dominant_race': 'white'}]
```

You see the `DeepFace.analyze(image)` method returns a list containing a dictionary. So, you need to address the list first, then the dictionary. Like this `predictions[0]['dominant_emotion']`:

```
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.1,4)

# draw rectangle around face
for (x, y ,w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
 
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

cv2.putText(img, predictions[0]['dominant_emotion'], (0,50), font, 1, (0,0,255), 2, cv2.LINE_4) 
cv2.imwrite('/content/download.jpeg', img)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Analyze function is returning a list for each face in the image.

If you are sure about that the number of faces in your image is equal to 1, then access first index

```
predictions = DeepFace.analyze(img)
print(predictions[0]['dominant_emotion'])
```

Or you can build a basic for loop

```
predictions = DeepFace.analyze(img)
for prediction in predictiosn:
   print(prediction ['dominant_emotion'])
```